# Modify Array Items to output smaller sub array with only one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I have below const

```
const cartProducts = props.cartSlice;
```

whose output is below array

```
Array [
  Object {
    "cartQuantity": 3,
    "product": "5f15d92ee520d44421ed8e9b",
  },
  Object {
    "cartQuantity": 2,
    "product": "5f15d964e520d44421ed8e9c",
  },
  Object {
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "product": "62e5285f92b4fde9dc8a384c",
  },
  Object {
    "cartQuantity": 4,
    "product": "5f15d9b3e520d44421ed8e9d",
  },
]
```

I am trying to write some code in reactjs to output separate arrays with the only the cartQuantity
as below

```
Array [
  3,
]
Array[
  2,
]
Array[
  1,
]
Array[
  4,
]
```

The closest I have come to achieving this is below which is consolidating all the cartQuantity in a single array.

```
const quantity = cartProducts.map((item, i) => item.cartQuantity);

Array [
  3,
  2,
  1,
  4,
]
```

How can I modify my query to output separate arrays for each cartQuantity?

Comment: Return `=> [item.cartQuantity]`

Answer (score 1):

You already mapped the initial array into an array of quantities, now if you want to get an array of arrays, with one quantity into each inner array, then it suffices to make the `map` callback return an Array with such quantity.

```js
const quantity = cartProducts.map((item, i) => [item.cartQuantity]);

Array [
  Array [
    3
  ],
  Array[
    2
  ],
  Array[
    1
  ],
  Array[
    4
  ]
]
```

Comment: It had not crossed my mind.. It is working and the console.log display an array of arrays. I thought it would address the problem I  faced here..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882335/render-display-quantity-items-correctly-in-react-reactjs